# Move an object a certain amount of pixels? - Python/Pygame

Tags: python, coordinates, pygame, move

Let's say I have an object and I've stored its x position, y position and the angle that it's facing (from 0 to 359). How would I find out the x and y position that it would be in if it travelled 10 pixels, for example?

I need this because I'm making a Pong game and I'm unsure of how to make the ball move. I'm aware it will involve trigonometry but that's as far I've got.

Basically, how would I complete this function:

```
def move_object(start_x, start_y, direction, pixels_to_move):
    #Return the x and y coordinates of where the object should move to
```

Comment: Do you know any trigonometry? It's easy if you do.

Answer (score 3):

[image: A lesson in 3 seconds]

Thereare30charactersinmyanswerbtwletmepost.